# IBM Cloud: How can I enable Public Access on a storage bucket from CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

I successfully enable Public Access to one of my buckets in IBM Cloud Object Storage and used the console (browser UI). [I followed these steps](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-iam-public-access). In the UI, the access group is shown as **Public Access** with ID **AccessGroupId-PublicAccess**. But I cannot find it when using the CLI, either when listing all access groups or trying to retrieve it directly:

`$ ibmcloud iam access-group AccessGroupId-PublicAccess`

> Retrieving access group AccessGroupId-PublicAccess under account Henrik's Account
> as HENRIK...
>
> FAILED Access group AccessGroupId-PublicAccess was not
> found

How can I see details on that access group, how can I assign a new policy to it for a given storage bucket?

Comment: Just verified the API and could see `AccessGroupId-PublicAccess` listed - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-access-groups#list-access-groups. May be this is missing in the CLI

Comment: I ran a CLI trace and the mismatch is that CLI is using V1 API and the latest API is V2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest IBM Cloud CLI update, the "Public Access" access group is visible. Now I can create and see public access policies for my Cloud Object Storage (COS) buckets:

Here is how I created a public access policy:

```
ibmcloud iam access-group-policy-create "Public Access" --roles "Content Reader" 
--service-instance 47b57632-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-03eb35b5ef23 --resource-type bucket
--resource henrik-fra-bucket-public-web --service-name cloud-object-storage
```

Thereafter, check that the policy exists for the access group "Public Access":

```
ibmcloud iam access-group-policies "Public Access" --output json
```

The output should be the same as if you would use the IBM Cloud console (Web UI).